# Is "trollopsing" a word, and if so, how is it used?

Tags: american-english, speech

Searches of "trollopsing" brings up a result in *Poems and Plays of John Masefield* where he uses the word. I also found it used on a Key and Peele sketch.

Otherwise, I can't seem to find any indication that it's a real word.

Is it a word, and what does it mean?

Edit with example: "I stayed at home for the past fifteen years taking care of mom and dad while you've been trollopsing all over the world."

Comment: Is it a reference to "meeting" a serious of trollops? Can you [edit] your question to provide the sentence or paragraph in which the word was used?

Comment: Context needed.

Comment: example sentence added.

Comment: I've come across this candidate word; it means 'gallivant'. Probably in OED.

Comment: My guess (before I saw the quote) was *trollopsing*: writing in the style of Anthony Trollope.

Comment: Reminds me of (one of the candidates for) the collective noun for sex workers: an _essay_ of trollops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not listed in the OED or any other major on-line dictionary.

Searching through google books, one finds this entry:

> **Trolloping** *part. adj.* Walking through dirt and mire, as a slattern does; trudging. **Sometimes 'Trollopsing'.**

This is an entry in *A Warwickshire Word-book: Comprising Obsolescent and Dialect Words, Colloquialisms, etc. Gathered from Oral Tradition, and Collated with Accordant Words* [(here)](https://books.google.com/books?id=Zy4_AAAAYAAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&dq=trollopsing&pg=PA250#v=onepage&q=trollopsing&f=false)

Therefore, for all intents and purposes, it is arguably not a word in Standard English.